# Assumptions failed in experimental design model

Tags: r, experiment-design, residuals, nonlinear-regression, assumptions

I'm dealing with a three-factor experimental design with two-factor interactions. The problem is model residuals does not fit any assumption (normality, homocedasticity and non-correlated residuals) and its distribution, yet symetrical around zero has a big kurtosis. My question is, should I try to transform original data in order to solve assumptions issues in linear model or is it better to use a generalized linear model?

Maybe I should mention that the observed variable ranges between 0 and 1, and I've already tried $log \left( \frac{y}{1-y} \right)$ transformation with no results.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Are the factors correlated at all?

Comment: Can you clarify what your observed variable stands for?

Comment: I don't know Beerhunter, but all treatments were applied to the subjects, so I don't think so

Comment: The observer variable is the entropy of a time series calculated using Bandt and Pompe algorithm.